# Recursive Javascript Function For Online Status

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following javascript.

```
function isOnline() {

var status = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline',
    indicator = document.getElementById('indicator'),
    current = indicator.textContent;

// only update if it has change
if (current != status) {

    // update DOM
    indicator.textContent = status;

    // trigger handler
    handler[status]();
};

if(current == 'offline')
{
  setInterval(checkServerStatus, 500)
  checkServerStatus();
 }
};




function checkServerStatus()
{
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.onload = function()
{
    alert('yey!');
    setInterval(isOnline, 500);
    isOnline();
};
img.onerror = function()
{
    alert('meh.')
};
img.src = "image-small.jpg";  //image on server(should be small so that intermittent checks are not bad)
}
$(checkServerStatus);
```

What I'd like to do is the following. 
First call checkServerStatus() -- > if online run isOnline() every 500ms to keep checking the status of the website. In my isOnline code if I ever check that it is offline, then run checkServerStatus again, and if I'm still connected go back.

In addition, I'd like to add two things to this, when checkServerStatus fails, recursively call another function isOnline2 to check until it is online, where I then call checkServerStatus again.

The issue I am currently running into right now is that checkServerStatus keeps showing the 'yey' alert. I thought that, the function only starts once, and then using setInterval(isOnline, 500) will continue to run. After isOnline changes to offline, then I would run my checkServerStatus function again.

Any ideas on how to adjust this would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: no need to keep checking, use events instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events\

Comment: I suspect the problem is with caching the image. Try adding a cache-buster to the URL.

Comment: Another important thing is to use cache busting with ping image. Otherwise load event will fire once image is cached.

Comment: like this `'image-small.jpg?' + ~~(Math.random() * 10000000);`

Comment: Thanks! I'll put this in.

Comment: @Ehtesham how do I do this for the img.src ? is it like 

mg.src = "http://stungeye.com/programs/flashthumbs/randomPixelScaleHigh.jpg" + ~~(Math.random() * 100000); ?

Answer (score 1):

Set your interval to a variable and then use clearInterval() when you want to stop your interval.

```
var interval = setInterval();
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: I dont get what you mean by this, because realistically I never want to stop the function isOnline, however I want checkServerStatus once in the beginning, and when isOnline hits offline, then I want to call it again until it changes back to Online

Comment: Well, look at it this way...you have one interval that is set to run an infinite number of times which is creating an infinite number of other intervals which are set to run an infinite number of times. You really need to be able to stop one or both of them and put more control around them so that they do not get out of hand (such as alerting over and over).

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` runs a function on an interval endlessly, until cancelled with `clearInterval()`.

In your case, I'd actually suggest not using `setInterval` but instead use `setTimeout`. This allows better control of execution: setTimeout runs once. At the completion of each function, you should be calling setTimeout to invoke either `checkServerStatus` or `isOnline`, as appropriate.

```
function isOnline() {

    .....

    if(current == 'offline') {
        setTimeout(checkServerStatus, 500);
    } else {
        setTimeout(isOnline, 500);
    }
};
```

It also prevents overlap: if, for example, `checkServerStatus` takes more than 500 ms to complete, with `setInterval` you'll be running it multiple times at the same time.

Comment: Hey, so I've tried it but unfortunately it still pops up every time... any other ideas?

Comment: Okay, so I got the popups to disappear which is awesome.. however I'm never getting an updated status on isOnline now